# Finding and Deleting a Node from this linked list in java

Tags: java

I have to write a program that implements a linked list of Students, in this case Student is a separate class that will be called. My linked List is supposed to be able to find a Student using the Name of that student and this is the area where my program fails it doesn't seem to find that Node for that Student, hence it also wont delete. I am writing this for a class and the professor does not allow the use of the built in Linked List class.

This is My Code

```
public class StudentList {

    StudentNode head;

    public StudentList() {

        shead = null;
    }

    public void setShead(StudentNode data) {

        shead = data;
    }

    public StudentNode getShead() {

        return shead;
    }

    public void insert(StudentNode data) {

        StudentNode iterator = head;

        if (iterator == null) {
            head = data;

        } else {
            while (iterator.getnext() != null) {
                iterator = iterator.getnext();

            }

            iterator.setnext(data);
        }
    }

    public void delete(StudentNode data) {

        StudentNode iterator = head;
        StudentNode current;

        if (iterator == data) {
            head = iterator.getnext();
        } else {
            while (iterator.getnext() != null) {
                if (iterator.getnext().equals(data)) {
                    // current
                    iterator.setnext(iterator.getnext().getnext());
                    // current.setSptr(iterator.getnext());
                    break;
                } else {
                    iterator = iterator.getSptr();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public StudentNode find(String n) {

        StudentNode iterator = head;
        StudentNode result = null;

        while (iterator.getnext() != null) {

            if (iterator.getStudent().getName().equals(n)) {
                result = iterator;
                System.out.println("" + iterator.getStudent().getName());
            } else {
                result = null;
            }
            iterator = iterator.getnext();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void print(){

            StudentNode iterator = head;

            while(iterator != null){
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ iterator.getStudent().getName()); 
                  iterator = iterator.getnext(); 
            }
      }
}
```

This is the Node

```
public class StudentNode{

      private Student data; 
      private StudentNode next;  

      public StudentNode(){

            data = null; 
            next = null; 
      }

      public StudentNode(Student data){

            this.data = data; 
            next = null; 
      }

      public Student getStudent(){

            return data; 
      }

      public void setStudent(Student data){

            this.data = data; 
      }

      public StudentNode getnext(){

            return next; 
      }

      public void setnext(StudentNode next){

            this.next = next; 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`if(iterator == data){` // <-- It just checks for same reference
              head = iterator.getnext(); 
        }
```

`if(iterator.getnext().equals(data)){` // <-- Here also, since you havent overridden `equals` method.. references will be comparaed

Also, I dont see you calling `find` method

You should override equals method in `StudentNode`, where you can compare `Student` object and check whether these are equal or not.